# Why is my gravatar on Meta Stack Overflow different from my gravatar on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, gravatar

Why is my gravatar on Meta Stack Overflow different than my gravatar on Stack Overflow? My profiles are:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10026/ykaganovich
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/10026/ykaganovich

Answer (score 12):

if you do not provide an email addres, the **Gravatar is based on the last IP you used to access either site**. You came in from two different IPs, so either..

1. provide an email address
2. access the sites from the same IP addresses

Gravatar is always IP or email based. Just depends what you give us.

Comment: I expected my ID to be used.

Comment: id would be redundant, we can already see that. gravatar gives us a visual hash of data that is NOT present, your IP/email.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to control your icon, you will first need to provide an email address to both sites (I can't speak for Stack Overflow, but we don't have one on file for you here on Meta). Then all you need to do is set up an account on [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) and link your email address to the image that you want to use as your icon here and on Stack Overflow.