# FAQ for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, faq

## Community FAQ

**For sites in the Stack Exchange 2.0 network**

To see a list of commonly used words and phrases, see the [glossary](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353).

For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the [Help Center](//meta.stackexchange.com/help).

### Asking questions

- [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647)
- [How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010)
- [Where can I ask a question about finding general software that meets certain requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411)
- [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724)
- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)
- [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)
- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)
- [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074)
- [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)
- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)
- [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527)

### Answering questions

- [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582)
- [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656)
- [How should you respond to "Give me a fish" / RTFM questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2686)
- [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)
- [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463)

### Accepting answers

- [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)
- [How do I see which of my questions are not accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86274)

### Working with posts

- What does it mean when a question or answer is...
- [closed](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582)?
- [locked](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228)?
- [deleted](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)?
- [protected](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764)?
- [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415)
- [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585)
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)
- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738)
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587)
- [Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870)
- [View or search for unanswered questions with a certain tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18545)
- [How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19126)
- [How does duplicate closing work? When is a question a duplicate, and how should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841)
- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249)
- [What are these notices above my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006)

### Comments

- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)
- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173)
- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)
- [How do I view the recent replies to things I have written?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45708)
- [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180)

### Etiquette

- [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029)
- [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232)
- [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280)
- [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17878)
- [What is the etiquette for correcting old questions with incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5408)
- [Etiquette for voting to close your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5215)
- [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17447)
- [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071)
- [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117)

### Promotion

- [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022)
- [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032)

### Editing and Formatting

- [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788)
- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)
- [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681)
- [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038)
- [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576)
- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)
- [Denoting keyboard shortcuts in Stack Exchange posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19145)
- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777)
- [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3792)
- [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734)
- [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491)
- [What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2133)
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009)
- [Why does the Community user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992)
- [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108)

### Tagging

- [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229)
- [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878)
- [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753)
- [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710)
- [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003)
- [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31776)
- [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187)
- [What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)
- [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949)

### Reputation, badges, and voting

- [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237)
- [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853)
- [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716)
- [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)
- [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648)
- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212)
- [When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046)
- [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364)
- [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350)
- [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004)
- [Why did I (not) receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege even though I (don't) have enough reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73673)
- [What are the limits and restrictions for new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564)
- [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)
- [How does the SO voter fraud detection mechanism work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19920)
- [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470)
- [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614)
- [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587)

### Moderation

- [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189)
- [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360)
- [What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4565)
- [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271267)
- [Flagging a post for moderator review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560)
- [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032)
- [Should I edit a question or answer with offensive content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22194)
- [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474)
- [Should an answer that encourages illegal activity be marked as "Offensive"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8492)
- [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)
- [I think I found some user accounts that should be merged; what do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98399)
- [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what does it do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338)
- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390)
- [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288)
- [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538)
- [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121)
- [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275)
- [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391)
- [When are moderator flags automatically dismissed as "aged away" by the system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204327)
- [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867)
- [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/)
- [When will CMs or moderators remove the [featured] tag from actively featured meta questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343527)

### Searching and RSS feeds

- [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229)
- [How do I make search return results that actually contain all the search terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14898)

### Accounts, registration and logging in

- [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557)
- [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232)
- [How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793)
- [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41277)
- [Why is my gravatar on Meta Stack Overflow different from my gravatar on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1681)
- [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17443)
- [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268)
- [What can I do to lift or reduce a suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316631)
- [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999)
- [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537)
- [How can I log in to my Stack Exchange account if I'm unable to use my current account provider?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138994)
- [I lost control of my account before registering. Can it be recovered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95358)
- [Why can't I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old, or if I'm under 16 years old and from the EU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770)

### Other

- [How often do CAPTCHAs appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343)
- [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199)
- [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)
- [Is Stack Overflow's content protected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60455)
- [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677)
- [What third-party tools are there for the trilogy websites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5188)
- [Who owns the content I post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18221)
- [What makes a winning site proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52066)
- [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974)
- [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)
- [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732)
- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445)
- [How are Stack Exchange sites officially branded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9024)
- [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369) ([blog post](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/))
- [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566)
- [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61541)
- [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132282)
- [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154797)
- [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)
- [Where can I find site community blogs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339115)
- [Which links and sites are handled specially (oneboxed) in chat? How do these oneboxes work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57286)
- [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109795)
- [What is the weekly newsletter? Who composes them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121630)
- [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)
- [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)
- [Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054)
- [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337)
- [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353)
- [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

### Site-specific entries

#### Stack Overflow

- [Should I send students to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254433)
- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
- [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22117)
- [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)
- [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754)

#### Meta Stack Exchange

- [What is Meta Stack Exchange, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47634)
- [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478)

#### Other

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598)

### External links

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)
- [Writing the Perfect Question by Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [What have you tried?](//mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202)

---

### Is your question not part of the FAQ?

First look at questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to see if there is a question not in this index that might have the answer you seek. If you still can't find an answer, then see the following instructions for proposing an FAQ question.

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body.
  The answer goes in an answer.
- **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:

  ```
   [Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)
  ```
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems
  to have hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
- Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet
  community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
- After the post has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag added to it, add a link in the above [table of contents](/q/7931).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything about RSS on the two pages linked in section *"Searching and RSS feeds"*.