# Why does my generic avatar keep changing?

Tags: support, profile-picture

I am using a generic avatar, and it changes daily. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: This may actually be magic ©

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Gravatars](https://www.gravatar.com/) are usually generated based on your hashed email address.

If you haven't supplied an email address, [it's based on your IP address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/why-is-my-gravatar-on-meta-stack-overflow-different-from-my-gravatar-on-stack-ove/1695#1695). If that changes daily, your Gravatar changes daily.